# Cumulative Sum Loop of Column Values in Python Reset Value at Specific Month each Year

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum values in a column and reset at a certain month every year.  I have checked the following links which have been helpful, but I still can't seem to find the answer that points me in the right direction.

[Cumulative sum at intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445729/cumulative-sum-at-intervals)
[Reset Cumulative sum base on condition Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784265/reset-cumulative-sum-base-on-condition-pandas)
[Conditional count of cumulative sum Dataframe - Loop through columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614476/conditional-count-of-cumulative-sum-dataframe-loop-through-columns)
[Pandas: conditional rolling count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count)

The link that has been the closest to what I am looking for ([Pyspark : Cumulative Sum with reset condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364686/pyspark-cumulative-sum-with-reset-condition)), but I can't figure out how to convert it from PySpark to Pandas (or another Python method.

```
raw_data = {'change_value': [-6, -13, -19, -82, -25, -39, -27, 0, 8, 32, 55, 94, 75, 77], 
        'cumu_value': [-6, -19, -38, -120, -145, -184, -211, -211, -203, -171, -116, -22, 75, 130], 
        'month': [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        'date': ['2017-10','2017-11','2017-12','2018-01','2018-02','2018-03'
                 ,'2018-04','2018-05','2018-06','2018-07','2018-08','2018-09',
                 '2018-10', '2018-11']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['change_value', 'cumu_value', 'month', 'date'])

df

df.loc[df['month'] == '10', ['cumu_value']] = df['change_value']

df['cumu_value'] = df.change_value.cumsum() 

change_value  cumu_value  month     date
0             -6     -6     10  2017-10
1            -13    -19     11  2017-11
2            -19    -38     12  2017-12
3            -82   -120      1  2018-01
4            -25   -145      2  2018-02
5            -39   -184      3  2018-03
6            -27   -211      4  2018-04
7              0   -211      5  2018-05
8              8   -203      6  2018-06
9             32   -171      7  2018-07
10            55   -116      8  2018-08
11            94    -22      9  2018-09
12            75     75     10  2018-10  <<<< every October I would like the to cumu_value to reset - to that month's change_value
13            77    130     11  2018-11 <<< for some reason the cumu_value adds all the values for all the months rather than just the value for 2018-10 and 2018-11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `groups` where the group_id changes every October. Then `cumsum` within each group, effectively resetting it every October.

```
df['cumu_value'] = df.groupby(df.month.eq(10).cumsum()).change_value.cumsum()
```

#### Output:

```
    change_value  cumu_value  month     date
0             -6          -6     10  2017-10
1            -13         -19     11  2017-11
2            -19         -38     12  2017-12
3            -82        -120      1  2018-01
4            -25        -145      2  2018-02
5            -39        -184      3  2018-03
6            -27        -211      4  2018-04
7              0        -211      5  2018-05
8              8        -203      6  2018-06
9             32        -171      7  2018-07
10            55        -116      8  2018-08
11            94         -22      9  2018-09
12            75          75     10  2018-10
13            77         152     11  2018-11
```

---

As an illustration, we are grouping rows together as follows:

```
print(df.month.eq(10).cumsum())
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    2
13    2
Name: month, dtype: int32
```

so we `cumsum` the first 12 rows separately from the last 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I thought I would add a solution that I found while running into the same issue. If you first set a DateTime index on your DataFrame you can use the following method using Pandas Grouper:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m')
df['cumu_valu'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='AS-OCT')).cumsum()['change_value']
```

This will output a column with cumulatively summed data that resets every October. If you want a different frequency, you can change the "freq='AS-OCT'" to the frequency of your choosing.